# Scrapy keeps giving me the errot AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been trying to build an aggregator and I've kept on getting the error stated in the title: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

```
import requests
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

query = input()
request = requests.get('https://google.com/search?', 
                       params={'q':query})

getLink = LinkExtractor()
for link in getLink.extract_links(request.text):
    print(link)
```

Comment: I recommand you to print ```request``` first then figure out what you want to do with it. The Error you encouter is because ```request``` is a string object, of course has no attribue named ```text```.

Answer (score 0):

LinkExtractor needs to work in Scrapy spider, parameter is Scrapy response, it's not a string object:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for link in self.link_extractor.extract_links(response):
        yield Request(link.url, callback=self.parse)
```